# How to execute custom pre deployment script on elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails app (rails 3.2.1, ruby 1.9.3 just in case) hosted on ec2 instance. On deploying to new instances, deploy fails because there are no seeds and the pre deployment script (12_db_migrate.sh) runs first causing it to fail. Manually seeding the db and then running migrate fixes it.

I want to create a pre deployment script under .ebextensions (I do not want to manually create a script under ...appdeploy/pre/ since that will not help me when I deploy the app on a new instance, say) Is this possible today ?

PS: I know that I do not want it to seed on every deploy so I am thinking of achieving that through environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option might be to re-evaluate why your migrations depend on particular data being seeded previously, but regardless I believe you can accomplish what you want via the `files` key.

Something like this would probably do the trick - I copied `12_db_migration.sh` and trimmed it down to just do the seed. By setting the prefix to `09_` it will run before the migration.

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/09_seed_database.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash

        EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
        EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir)
        EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
        EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)

        . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars

        . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

        cd $EB_APP_STAGING_DIR

        su -s /bin/bash -c "leader_only bundle exec rake db:seed" $EB_APP_USER
```

Comment: I agree with your first part of the comment that the migrations needed to be reevaluated. I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails but I can say that the code is in a pretty messy state. I did try to use the "files" key as you have mentioned but it still went ahead and ran the migration first and failed ( I did validate the YAML ). Anyways, I ended up executing the seeds as a migration (I know its a hack but it looked the cleanest of all the other automated approaches I could think of).

Answer (score 0):

You can tell elastic beanstalk to run container_commands pre deployment, by adding a file `.ebextensions/packages.config` containing something like

```
container_commands:
  01_node_install_if_not_installed:
    cwd: /tmp
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/node ] && echo "node not installed"'
    command: 'echo "e" > tst.txt'
    leader_only: true
```

- `cwd`, `test` and `leader_only` are optional.
- `command` will only run if `test` evaluates true
- `leader_only` sets whether or not to do it on the first ec2 instance (in case you're using multiple)

PS! You cannot use `eb setenv` to set environment variables that should be acted on during this stage, as those environment variables are used by a webapp-user, while these commands are run with root.

Comment: container_commands are executed AFTER the appdeploy/pre hooks are executed. That is not what I want.